# retard vs delay in scientific writing

Tags: word-choice

In scientific writing,
1.appearance of some phenomenon delays
vs
2.appearance of some phenomenon retards
Which is better? Also wonder about the noun form delay vs retardation.
For example, sth delays/retards the onset of a chemical reaction.

Comment: Did you do a google search to see how these appear and how often?

Comment: It depends on the context. Without context, it's a matter of opinion. *Some substances retard the spread of fire*; *traffic delays the firemen*.

Comment: pls c the context i added in the question

Answer (score 2):

Delay implies stagnation, as in a pause of progress, remaining at the current stage.
Retard implies an active regression, as in moving to a lesser stage of progress.
So it depends on what you're trying to say about the appearance of said phenomenon

Comment: Is this a meaning specific to scientific writing?  I have never heard *retard* used to mean *cause to regress*, only ever *to slow*.

Comment: From my experience in science retarding is a reduction in speed, i.e. a reduction in the rate of distance covered. So if you're thinking about distance its slowing, but if your talking about speed it's regressing, but its definitely open to interpretation.

Comment: pls c the context i added in the question